# Accessing internal websites through VPN on iPad using SSO

Tags: vpn, ios, single-sign-on, ipad

We are having an iOS issue with users trying to access our internal websites through a VPN connection.

We use SSO to access these sites and everything works for a Windows user as the Domain is Windows-based.

However, when iPad users access sites through a VPN (when they are offsite) they are prompted with a login box. As you can imagine this makes a few of them angry.

We are trying to figure out the best way to remove the need to ask for login details once the iOS user has connected using VPN.

So, my question is, can this be done by configuring the IIS server to use VPN details to help solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like you should invest in some surface tablets that can be domain-joined.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, as they are not domain joined. (as iis send the current logged on credential to the remote site, thus it fail and ask a login)

A workaround would be to invest to use a broker (xenapp or rdp) to publish the website link. As after the first connection you can allow in the local client in the ipad to save the credential used after the first login. Be aware if the password change the user need to resave the new credential anyhow. (or do like EEAA told, use a surface tablet)

Comment: Thanks for the replay, xenapp/ rdp sounds a bit overkill for us. Would it be possible to join the iPads to the domain once the user has connected through the VPN? Something like SSL VPN? Surface tablets are tempting at the moment - its never easy mixing devices from apple with microsoft!

Comment: @user367677 no, thus you have not much choice there. (please comment there, not in another awnser!)

Comment: @user367677 a side note, a sslvpn in radius mode with a html portal could work, but you ask your user to log on a site to save the other site login...